# Scala's mutable.ListBuffer seems to use List's tail function yet it is documented as having linear complexity?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

As of scala's 2.12.8 [current documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html), List's tail is constant and ListBuffer's tail is linear. However, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala), it looks like there is no overwrite for the tail function and in most use-cases (such as remove the head element), List's tail function is explicitly called. Since ListBuffer seems to be little more than a List wrapper with a length var and a pointer to the last element, why is it linear?

I timed both methods and indeed it seems like List's tail is constant and ListBuffer's tail is indeed linear:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.immutable

val immutableList: immutable.List[Int] = (1 to 10000).toList
val mutableListBuffer: mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Int] ++= (1 to 10000).toList

// Warm-up
(1 to 100000).foreach(_ => immutableList.tail)
(1 to 100000).foreach(_ => mutableListBuffer.tail)

// Measure
val start = System.nanoTime()
(1 to 1000).foreach(_ => immutableList.tail)
val middle = System.nanoTime()
(1 to 1000).foreach(_ => mutableListBuffer.tail)
val stop = System.nanoTime()

println((middle - start) / 1000)
println((stop - middle) / 1000)
```

The results were, as documented:

```
1076
86010
```

However, if you use functions such as remove(0) that use List's tail, it is constant with the following results:

```
1350
1724
```

I expect that the linearity complexity comes from building a whole new list to return, but since the internal structure is a List, why not return the List's tail?

Comment: Because it is mutable.

Comment: @talex `ListBuffer#tail` doesn't mutate anything, though.

Comment: @TravisBrown Yes. It is made the way it is to handle next scenario. Get tail, then mutate original list. Tail will remain in exact same state as you get it.

Comment: I guess the reason is `drop(1)` call inside `tail`. at this point, we create new list buffer  with linear complexity

Comment: @talex That's not really an explanation, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ListBuffer` doesn't extend `List`, and the fact that it doesn't override `tail` doesn't mean it's using `List#tail`. If you look at the *Definition Classes* section of the docs for [`tail` on `ListBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html#tail:Repr), you'll see that it comes from `TraversableLike`, where it's defined like this:

```
override def tail: Repr = {
  if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.tail")
  drop(1)
}
```

And if you look at `drop`, you'll see that it uses a builder to construct a new collection containing all but the first element, which explains why it's linear.

As talex hints at in the comments above, `ListBuffer#tail` has to return a new collection because the original buffer could be modified, and the standard library designers have decided that you wouldn't want those modifications reflected in the result you get from `tail`.

Comment: I see. I wonder why wouldn't the default behavior be to just return a immutable list, as returning a mutable subsection of a mutable collection sounds a bit behaviorally undefined (I would have the expectation that changes to the original mutable list would be reflected on the reference on some languages).

Comment: For consistency `ListBuffer#tail` really _has_ to return a `ListBuffer`—the Scala collections library is a confusing mess already, but if methods like `tail` returned different types it'd be much worse.

Comment: It's not mutable to not confuse user by changing type of collection. Returning linked collection make semantic complicated. Imagine scenario when you clean original buffer. Tail became invalid.

Comment: Yes, a shared state mutable list and tail would be dangerous to use and of little use (even though I can imagine some uses), but I see a mutable copy of the original mutable list of little use as well. I get the point of not wanting to mix types within a collection, but it already happens and a collections paradigm where a immutable type is just a more specific type of a mutable one would be easier to conceptualize (and if the focus is on immutability, it could be seen as the other way around). I would have no problem with copy operations returning immutable versions.

Answer (score 1):

> since the internal structure is a List

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala), the internal structure is actually two lists:

```
private var start: List[A] = Nil
private var last0: ::[A] = _
```

`last0` has this type because it's mutated using internal API <s>(and it has to be for `ListBuffer` to make sense)</s> (actually, just having two lists for the front and back parts with the back part in the reverse order should support all `ListBuffer` operations quite efficiently, including (amortized) O(1) `tail`; presumably the current implementation wins on constant factors, or maybe I am missing some operation it does much better).

So `tail` can't just "return the List's tail": it would at the least have to copy `last0` because you can't share the same mutable part between two buffers. Even if the designers wanted changes to `tail` to reflect changes to the original `ListBuffer` and vice versa, sharing `last0` wouldn't have this effect 
(without a lot more effort). This is already linear.

Note that if return type of `ListBuffer#tail` were `List` you also need to copy `last0`, or copy the contents from `last0` to `start` before returning its tail, etc. So it doesn't make `tail` constant-time. But it does create additional problems: does `ArrayBuffer#tail` return `Array`? How do you declare `tail`'s return type in [`GenTraversableLike`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.html) if it's still available there?

Comment: I don't buy the "because" here. You absolutely could imagine a collections API where `tail` on a mutable collection reflected changes in the original collection. That's just not what the library designers decided to do.

Comment: @TravisBrown Yes, but you wouldn't get this by just sharing `last0`, so this wouldn't help with making `tail` constant-time (at least by itself). Clarified what I meant there.